# db query for retrieving comments without any reply

Tags: comments, query, wpdb

what is a query for selecting a list of comment id's that have not had a reply yet so I can use it to iterate though each comment id and echo out the post it is on and the excerpt of the comment along with the author name, url and how many comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work...

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$sql = "SELECT comment_ID FROM ". $wpdb->prefix ."comments WHERE comment_parent = 0 AND comment_ID NOT IN(SELECT comment_parent FROM ". $wpdb->prefix ."comments);";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
?>
```

Comment: actually I spoke too soon! it works but it brings back every comment that hasn't had a reply. 
what is a query for bringing back top level comments that haven't had a reply?